# Average Hour of Day in Teradata

Tags: sql, datetime, timestamp, teradata

I have a table with hundreds of timestamps.

I extract the hour, then I can simply average that, however, this is where I get issues.

```
select purchase,
CAST(AVG(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM opened_at)) AS INT) as average_open
            from db.purchasetable 
group by 1
```

When I average hour 22 and hour 2 I get 12(obviously), however, what I want is 0 cause midnight is the average point in time between the two hours.

How do I do this in Teradata?

Comment: I'm not sure that it is possible at all, as average between 2 and 22 still should be 12, not 0, probably you need to re-think your requirments

Comment: 0 would not be the average point - it would be a midway point. Are you looking for the time of day when most people will be active? That might be easier.

Comment: If you want the day to be relevant, then you need to include the day to be included in your average calculation. That of course means you'd still have an issue at month end - so you should include the month. Then year end... include the year. So it really comes down to what you're trying to achieve here :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. What I'm looking for is a workaround to give me 0 in sql

Comment: To add to that comment, I want the average time of day not average date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do an average on `time`, but it's allowed for `interval` :-)

Subtracting two times return an interval:

```
AVG(CAST(opened_at AS TIME(0))            -- extract only the time portion
     - TIME '12:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND(0)) -- subtract 12 hours to center at midnight (returns an interval)
+ TIME '00:00:00'                         -- change it back to a time
```

If you still want an hour as result you can simply extract it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your premises. Consider hours as different lengths of string all starting at the same place (midnight). So the average length of two strings, one of length 22 and the other of length 2 is 12.

That is, the average between 2am and 10pm is noon, not midnight (length=0). The fact that these hours occur on different days is incidental.

So you had the right answer all along.

Comment: I appreciate that 12 is mathamatically the correct answer however i'm looking for a workaround to give me midnight.

Comment: Your question concerns AVERAGE. Midnight is not an average of the two times you provide, it is the halfway period between them. You can write a function to return the halfway period between two periods, but it would appear from your question that you are looking at more than just two dates. Can you state, in plain English, exactly what you are looking for?